# A question from Professor Anthony Zee's book: "Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, magnetic-monopoles

When Professor Anthony Zee is discussing the topological monopole in page 309 of his famous book ["Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691140340), Princeton University Press (2010), he writes:

[image]

But I am still not clear how the mass of the topological monopole, which is related to the mass of intermediate vector boson of the weak interaction, explains that why the monopole has not yet been discovered. Could anyone help me to explain this? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $W$ boson has a mass of about 80 GeV, 137$M_W$ would make a mass of about 11 TeV which is way above the mass of the highest-energy particles recently detected, such as the Higgs Boson which weighs about 125 GeV.