# Have we observed magnetic monopole already? If not, why?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, magnetic-monopoles

Please see '[here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/237830/)' for the energy scale of a (topological) magnetic monopole. It is around 11 TeV and I am impressed that the LHC reaches the scale of 14TeV already. Then have we observed the monopole already? If not, why?

Comment: Probably because they don't exist, I guess.

Comment: Seems like too much of a simplistic and presumptive statement to bluntly say "the mass of the magnetic monopole is $M_W/\alpha$"

Comment: We know that without magnetic monopoles there would be no limit on the strength of magnetic fields in vacuum [see eq. 8 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0002442), which is unphysical. For me that's good enough to say that we've observed the magnetic monopole, because "observation" is ultimately information extracted from Nature via experiments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially LHC was not designed to detect exotic objects like magnetic monopole. Only recently (in 2010) a new detector named MoEDAL (The Monopole & Exotics Detector at the LHC) has been installed in LHC, which in particular has designed to detect **new particles** like magnetic monopole or   massive (pseudo-)stable charged particles.

This new detector (MoEDAL) has started operating from 2015. Data acquired in this experiment yet to analyzed. Therefore we have to wait to see the outcome of this new experiment. For a technical detail on LHC's monopole search, one can consult with this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06645). CERN's Official webpage for this experiment can be found [here](http://moedal.web.cern.ch/).

Comment: It is 2017 now. Has the data been analysed yet?

Answer (score -3):

The data has yet to be validated by a series of upcoming experiments and according to the current techniques, they might have to rethink the approach due to plenty of shortcomings described in their paper.

Comment: What data, what paper, and what experiments are you referring to?